# How to add media from front-end to an existing post?

Tags: attachments, uploads, front-end

[Golden Apples Design](http://goldenapplesdesign.com/2010/07/03/front-end-file-uploads-in-wordpress/) created (as far as I know) the media upload function that many people on WP.A and elsewhere seem to recommend. But all of the Q&As I can find on StackExchange deal with creating an entirely new post.

What is the best way to get this (or another snippet) to upload media from the front-end, attach it to the current post, generate the appropriate thumbnails, and then refresh the page showing the new image in the [gallery]?

Here is Than's code:
In functions file...

```
function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {

  // check to make sure its a successful upload
  if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

  $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

  if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
  return $attach_id;
```

In page template header...

```
// set $post_id to the id of the post you want to attach
// these uploads to (or 'null' to just handle the uploads
// without attaching to a post)

if ($_FILES) {
  foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$post_id);
    // $newupload returns the attachment id of the file that
    // was just uploaded. Do whatever you want with that now.
  }
}
```

Upload form used...

```
<form method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <input type="file" name="an_uploaded_attachment">
  <input type="file" name="another_uploaded_attachment">
  <input type="file" name="yet_another_uploaded_attachment">
  <input type="submit">
<form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@AboSami actually [answered this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5673/using-upload-image-with-media-handle-upload-but) in an older post that was not showing up in my search diligence. While he was actually looking for something else his example code worked great.

Here's the script:

```
<?php $post_id = $post->ID;
if ( isset( $_POST['html-upload'] ) && !empty( $_FILES ) ) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
    $id = media_handle_upload('async-upload', $post_id); //post id of Client Files page
    unset($_FILES);
    if ( is_wp_error($id) ) {
        $errors['upload_error'] = $id;
        $id = false;
    }

    if ($errors) {
        echo "<p>There was an error uploading your file.</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Your file has been uploaded.</p>";
    }
}

?>
    <form id="file-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="POST">

    <p id="async-upload-wrap"><label for="async-upload">upload</label>
    <input type="file" id="async-upload" name="async-upload"> <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="html-upload"></p>

    <p><input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo $post_id ?>" />
    <?php wp_nonce_field('client-file-upload'); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" /></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Save all changes" name="save" style="display: none;"></p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your header change `$post_id` to `$post->ID`.

```
// set $post_id to the id of the post you want to attach
// these uploads to (or 'null' to just handle the uploads
// without attaching to a post)

if ($_FILES) {
  foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$post->ID);
    // $newupload returns the attachment id of the file that
    // was just uploaded. Do whatever you want with that now.
  }
}
```

Comment: I had already accounted for that.  :)